# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-urls

I got the error:

`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

When write:

`https://chalets.com:8000/accounts/login` in URL. I notice that when remove namespace and app_name of accounts from urls.py, the URL reverse to login successfully. I want to know why raise error when use namespace?
and how solve the error?

Here is urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    path('social-auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
    path('', include('homepage.urls', namespace='home')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and the urls.py of accounts:

```
from django.urls import path
from accounts.views import SignUpView, LogoutView, LoginView

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup', SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('login', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout')
]
```

views.py:

```
class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class    = SignUpForm
    template_name = 'signup.html' 
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # get data from form
        email     = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password1 = form.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = form.cleaned_data['password2']
        # save user in database with hash password
        user      = User(email=email, password=password1)
        user.set_password(password1)
        user      = user.save()
        # authenticate, login, and redirect to home
        user      = authenticate(email=email, password=password1)
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('home')



class LoginView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    form_class    =  LoginForm 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # get data from for and authenticate
        email    = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user     = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        
        if user is not None:
            login(self.request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.info(self.request, 'invalid username or password')
            return redirect('accounts:login')



class LogoutView(views.LogoutView):
    next_page = '/'
```

Comment: How does the `SignUpView`, `LoginView` and `LogoutView` looks like?

Comment: I edit the question and added views.py